# pandas - interpolate time series only if missing time window is between timedelta limit

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I would like to use the pandas interpolate function to fill the missing values of a pandas series where the index is a datetime.

Is there a way to apply the interpolate function only on the gaps which are between certain limits? Let's say we want to use it only on gaps that are shorter than datetime.timedelta(minutes=A) and longer than datetime.timedelta(minutes=B).

Let's say A=30, B=15 and we have this time series

```
2018-07-01 12:00:00    1
2018-07-01 12:05:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:10:00    3
2018-07-01 12:15:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:20:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:25:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:30:00    7
2018-07-01 12:35:00    8
2018-07-01 12:40:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:45:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:50:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:55:00    nan
2018-07-01 13:00:00    nan
2018-07-01 13:05:00    14
```

, I would like to have

```
2018-07-01 12:00:00    1
2018-07-01 12:05:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:10:00    3
2018-07-01 12:15:00    4
2018-07-01 12:20:00    5
2018-07-01 12:25:00    6
2018-07-01 12:30:00    7
2018-07-01 12:35:00    8
2018-07-01 12:40:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:45:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:50:00    nan
2018-07-01 12:55:00    nan
2018-07-01 13:00:00    nan
2018-07-01 13:05:00    14
```

For now, I've found only solutions to filter the gaps on their number of rows...

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mind to share a sample of your original `df` and the expected output?

Comment: ok, I've modified the question

Comment: no idea on this? :( :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is going to work in a more general case but you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range(start="2018-07-01 12:00:00",
                                         end="2018-07-01 13:05:00",
                                         freq="5min")})
df["value"] = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)
df["value"] = np.where(df.index.isin([1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]),
                       np.nan,
                       df["value"])

# Interpolation
df["value"] = np.where((df.date.dt.minute >=15) & (df.date.dt.minute <=30),
                       df.value.interpolate(),
                       df.value)
```